# GET Response having URLs in them

Tags: java, rest, jersey

We are implementing a REST based GET implementation which returns back a list of multiple URIs in the response payload back to the client. Later the client uses each one of those URIs and then does a GET on each individual URI to get back a seperate payload. Aren't URIs returned in Location or Content-Location header only after a new Resource is created by POST.

Is the below kind of implementation violating REST standards?

```
  **Initial Call** 

  GET /AllURIs
  HTTP 200 OK
  content-type:applicaton/xml
     <URIs>
       <URI> /somelocation/1 </URI>
       <URI> /somelocation/2 </URI>
       <URI> /somelocation/3 </URI>
       <URI> /somelocation/4 </URI>
       <URI> /somelocation/5 </URI>
    <URIs>

     **Later Call**

     GET /somelocation/1
     <NewObject>
      .........
     </NewObject>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs can be returned in scenarios other than posting a new resource, like pagination.

If you have multiple related URLs to any resource, the best way IMO is to add them in Link header instead of returning in the response payload. We have used this approach for pagination urls where we sent next, previous, first and last urls as a part of [Link Header](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader)

Having said that, if the sole purpose of your REST request is to obtain (GET) a list of URLs and that is how you have designed your resources, then it should be okay to use URLs in response body also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the absolute URL rather than relative ones. You may use the structure like you propose - it is OK, but you may also consider using the Atom links.